# passing a parameter with onclick function is read as a variable when it should be read as a string

Tags: javascript, dynamic, parameters, onclick

Here is my issue:

I am creating dynamically a button with an onclick function like this:

```
 $("#test).html('<input type="button" value="Close" onclick="remove('+param1+','+param2+');" />');
```

The parameters are well read but the function is not trigger, and I've got this error message:
"bob is not defined" when bob is the string value of the param1.

Apparently it seems that bob is read as a variable when it should be read as a string, but I don't understand why.

Thanks much for your help!

Comment: Welcome to SO. On about writing a question or an answer, use the toolbox to format correctly the code otherwise it is not visible. Use the [?] on the toolbox for more details. Also check the question preview below the editing zone to see what's it going to look like.

Answer (score 5):

That's because this string right here:

```
'onclick="remove('+param1+','+param2+');"'
```

Will look like this in the end:

```
'onclick="remove(foo, bar);"'
```

You probably want it to look like this:

```
'onclick="remove(\'foo\', \'bar\');"'
```

So change it to this:

```
'onclick="remove(\''+param1+'\', \''+param2+'\');"'
```

You could also do this:

```
$("#test").html('<input type="button" value="Close" />').find('input[type=button]').click(function () {
    remove(param1, param2);
});
```

Edit: I also noticed that you were missing one " from your $()-call: `$("#test)` should be `$("#test")`.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest you this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    var i = 0;
    $(function () {
        $("#lnkAdder").click(function () {
            // appending new item
            $("#Container").append(
                $("<a>").attr({ "href": "javascript:;" }).text("Click me").click(function () {
                    var data = ++i;
                    alert("I'm clicked,  I'm number " + data);
                })
            );
        });
    });
//]]>
</script>
<a href="javascript:;" id="lnkAdder">Add item</a>
<div id="Container"></div>
```

The key here is the javascript closure.
As you can see there a link called `lnkAdder`. It is responsible to add anew item into the container. On click it appends a new item into the container. While appending you use jQuery API and create a new element, add attributes and add event listener. In the event listener body you copy the value into an internal variable. They use it as appropriate.